# paragraph and anchor as a button / how add server side event click

Tags: asp.net, button, anchor, server-side

hi my dear firends :
i have a button like below :

```
            <p id="EnterToImagesParag" class="EnterParag">
                <a id="EnterToImagesLink" name="EnterToImagesLink" class="EnterLink">
                </a>
            </p>
```

and css :

```
p.EnterParag, p.EnterParag a.EnterLink
{
   width: 400px;
   height: 45px;
   display: block;
}
p#EnterToImagesParag
{
    background: url(/Images/Admin/btnConfigImages.png) 0px -45px;
}
p#EnterToImagesParag a#EnterToImagesLink
{
    background: url(/Images/Admin/btnConfigImages.png) 0px 0px;
}
```

and jquery Like this :

```
        $(document.body).ready(function () {
            $('.EnterParag a').hover(
            function () { $(this).stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 500); },
            function () { $(this).stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 500); });
});
```

how can i add server side event click to this button ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, that's not a `button`, it's an `anchor`. You can add a server side event by adding `runat=server` and an event handler for the `OnServerClick` event.

```
 <a id="EnterToImagesLink" name="EnterToImagesLink" class="EnterLink" runat="server" OnServerClick="MyClickEvent"> </a>
```

Comment: @keyboardP thanks for attention -> just a moment / i am testing it!

Comment: ok / it works perfect / thanks a lot! but is there another way/s for learning?

Comment: @LostLord - Arief's suggestion of using `asp:LinkButton` can also be used as well. You can also use jQuery to handle the click and fire a server side event (using `eval`). An example of that is here: http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/08/call-aspnet-server-side-event-in-jquery.html Depending on your needs, you can also use jQuery with AJAX http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: +1: really wonderful. i didnt even know `OnServerClick` existed. wow. things i learn everyday :)

Comment: It's why I love SO - I always learn at least one new thing each visit :)

Answer (score 1):

you can replace the anchor element "a" with ASP.NET control LinkButton control, it will produce the same type of HTML element (anchor/"a") and it provides you with Click event as well (server side).

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myLinkButton" runat="server" CssClass="EnterLink" Text="My LinkButton" OnClick="OnServerClickMethod" />
```

Comment: pal hyperlink doesn't have a click event. alter before somebody -1 you. :)

Comment: @LostLord, you can still apply styling on server controls. Use CssClass property to set CSS class to server control.

Comment: +1: it happens all day for me :) but i think keyboardP answer is more apt to the context :)